# Go: Using using a string in a []byte function type argument?

Tags: go, markdown

I'm begginer to Go. I'm trying to use [blackfriday](https://github.com/russross/blackfriday/blob/master/markdown.go) (a Go Markdown parser). This is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/russross/blackfriday"
)

func main() {
    input := "this is a test"
    output := blackfriday.MarkdownCommon(input)

    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

I got an error, though:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/go/src/m2kgo$ go run m2kgo.go
# command-line-arguments
./m2kgo.go:20: cannot use input (type string) as type []byte in argument to blackfriday.MarkdownCommon
```

So I tried turning the argument into `[]byte`:

```
output := blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(input))
```

This output the bytes though:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/go/src/m2kgo$ go run m2kgo.go
[60 112 62 116 104 105 115 32 105 115 32 97 32 116 101 115 116 60 47 112 62 10]
```

How can I print the generated HTML instead of the bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert it back to a string.

`fmt.Println(string(output))`

Comment: Oh, thanks. Is that something that's commonly done in Go (changing the input/output type)? Or I'm using them in a wrong way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the blackfriday package so I can't comment on how that's supposed to work -- but in general it's not uncommon to have to convert types when manipulating data

Comment: Looking at their source, it looks like they take in and return []bytes everywhere, so yes -- I think you're on the right track. https://github.com/russross/blackfriday/blob/master/markdown.go#L250