# How to use string literals in go

Tags: go, string-literals

In a go template I want to replace the the strings below with variables:

```
bot := DigitalAssistant{"bobisyouruncle", "teamAwesome", "awesomebotimagename", "0.1.0", 1, 8000, "health", "fakeperson@gmail.com"}
```

Say I want to replace `bobisyouruncle` with the variable `input`

### How can I do this?

In js this is simply:

```
bot := DigitalAssistant{`${input}`, "teamAwesome", "awesomebotimagename", "0.1.0", 1, 8000, "health", "fakeperson@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: Use `bot := DigitalAssistant{input, "teamAwesome"....` to replace a string literal with a variable.  There's no need for a string-template feature.

Comment: That's the opposite of a string literal, it's what's often called a template or interpolation. In this case, if `input` is a string, you don't need any of that - just use `DigitalAssistant{input, "teamAwesome",...`. But there's not enough code shown to say what you actually need here.

Comment: I cannot just put `input` because go gives the error `cannot use input (type []byte) as type string in field value`

Comment: You can trivially [convert a byte slice it to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757340/go-using-using-a-string-in-a-byte-function-type-argument).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Go, there is no such thing as string template literals such as on the es6. However, you can definitely do something similar by using [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

```golang
fmt.Sprintf("hello %s! happy coding.", input)
```

In your case it would be:

```golang
bot := DigitalAssistant{
    fmt.Sprintf("%s", input),
    "teamAwesome",
    "awesomebotimagename",
    "0.1.0",
    1,
    8000,
    "health",
    "fakeperson@gmail.com",
}
```

---

A curious question by the way. Why need to use string template literals on a very straightforward string like `${input}`? why not just `input`?

---

## EDIT 1

> I cannot just put input because go gives the error cannot use input (type []byte) as type string in field value

`[]byte` is convertible into string. If your `input` type is `[]byte`, simply write it as `string(input)`.

```golang
bot := DigitalAssistant{
    string(input),
    "teamAwesome",
    "awesomebotimagename",
    "0.1.0",
    1,
    8000,
    "health",
    "fakeperson@gmail.com",
}
```

---

## EDIT 2

> why can't I do the same if the value is an int? So for the values in the brackets 1 and 8000 I can't just do `int(numberinput)` or `int(portinput)` or I'll get the error `cannot use numberinput (type []byte) as the type int in field value`

Conversion from `string` to `[]byte` or vice versa can be achieved by using the [explicit conversion `T(v)`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). However, this method is not applicable across all types.

For example, to convert `[]byte` into `int` more effort is required.

```golang
// convert `[]byte` into `string` using explicit conversion
valueInString := string(bytesData) 

// then use `strconv.Atoi()` to convert `string` into `int`
valueInInteger, _ := strconv.Atoi(valueInString) 

fmt.Println(valueInInteger)
```

I suggest taking a look at [go spec: conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

Comment: I had the same question, seems like such a straightforward thing, but I'm filling variables in a struct to write to a template so I need to pass strings. I was aware of this method but it seemed a bit much compared to what es6 can do, so I wanted to ask.

Comment: Thank you, I'm making such basic mistakes in this new language. I like it, just have to go through growing pains I guess.

Comment: Another question, why can't I do the same if the value is an int? So for the values in the brackets `1` and `8000` I can't just do `int(numberinput)` or `int(portinput)` or I'll get the error `cannot use numberinput (type []byte) as the type int in field value`

Comment: @MelodyAnoni I put my updated answer. explaining in comment will be harder. please take a look

Comment: Thank you, you've helped me a lot